# Can’t submit code to Gerrit (review.cyanogenmod.org)

Tags: android, git, gerrit, repository, cyanogenmod

I’ve made some changes and want to submit code. I get this error:

```
repo upload bootable/recovery
Upload project bootable/recovery/ to remote branch refs/heads/cm-11.0:
  branch cm-11.0 ( 1 commit, Fri Jan 3 21:42:34 2014 +0400):
         *************************
to review.cyanogenmod.org (y/N)? y
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
[FAILED] bootable/recovery/ cm-11.0         (Upload failed)
```

NOTE: I’ve alredy added ssh-rsa keys, and my username on pc is the same as at review.cyanogenmod.org. I was following [CyanogenMod’s instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_using_gerrit).

Comment: what was the command? if you used origin as target then please provide as the output of  git config --get remote.origin.url

Comment: Your username/pubkey configuration is not working. See the "Permission denied" message. Make sure that `ssh user@review.cyanogenmod.org -p 29418` us working. In doubt as the path to your private key via the `-i` parameter. If that works, set up your `.ssh/config` for to use that key.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[review.review.cyanogenmod.org]
    username = <your gerrit username here>
```